# How is Tony Stark so rich?

Tags: marvel

How did Iron Man become so rich? Since he's a superhero, I hope that he wouldn't do anything illegal such as tax evasion. I understand that he's one of the big leaders among the Avengers, but it's not like he's getting paid to do his job...is he?

Perhaps I don't know enough about the Marvel Universe.

Comment: *"Howard Anthony Stark was heir to a railroad dynasty, and used his vast talents in science to expand and enrich the family business. He and his father founded Stark Industries, which specialized in engineering and technology, eventually gaining a widespread reputation as a company on the cutting edge."* https://www.marvel.com/characters/howard-stark/in-comics

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [How does Stark Enterprises maintain its cashflow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15128)

Comment: I think it's different enough. That question is asking how they maintained income during a specific time after Tony stopped being an arms dealer. This question is asking how he inherited money in the first place and will open up to not only Tony Stark, but how his father started Stark Industries.

Comment: Have you ever seen a poor weapon's manufacturer?

Comment: This question is literally answered in the first 10 mins of the 1st Iron Man movie!

Answer (score 8):

His father, Howard Stark, created Stark Industries and was developing weapons for the U.S. military. Stark Industries develops and sells weapons to militaries all over the world. Tony inherited Stark Industries after his fathers death.

In the movie *Iron Man* his own weapons are responsible for his capture. That's when he discovers Obadiah was selling weapons to bad people behind his back.

He creates the Iron Man suit, but refuses to give that technology away. Only Rhodey (a.k.a. War Machine) was given one.

Being an Avenger doesn't pay well according to Falcon in *The Falcon And The Winter Soldier*.

Comment: Note also that Tony inherited Stark Industries from his dad, who was also an inventor.

Comment: Correct, added more information.

Answer (score 2):

His father was already a weapons contractor for the USA during WW2. Besides supplying weapons to the USA they were also supplying weapons to pretty much anyone else who was willing to buy them (even terrorists, thanks to Obadiah) until Tony stopped him.

60 years of dominating the arms market is kinda a sure thing to become rich, and even after leaving the arms dealing Stark Industries still developed and sold new tech (like S.H.I.E.L.D.'s new helicarrier engines during *Winter Soldier*, probably not free of charge).